# Code doesn't enter in if(match.Success)

Tags: c#, regex

Something is wrong with this code. It doesn't extract value of required Regex. I put Regex to extract `percentage` but code doesn't enter in **IF(match.Success)** condition.

```
for (int l = 0; l < resplitted.Length; l++)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(resplitted[l]);
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^0*(100\.00|[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})%$");

    Match match = regex.Match(resplitted[l]);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        bsc =double.Parse(match.Value);
        MessageBox.Show(bsc.ToString()); // I want here something like 90%,10.1% etc.

    }

}
```

Comment: This means that the match is unsuccessful. What's the strings in `resplitted`?

Comment: Its string array actually, It sometimes 90% , age, name etc. When its 90% i want a break.

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq Well of course those don't match, your regex requires two decimals after the separator :)

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed?

Comment: @HVD, Please correct my regex then :)

Comment: @Casimer- No, they are not.

Comment: Why the downvotes This is a good question, complete with a set of code. With the comment in place, it's clear what problem the OP wants to fix.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight- Thanks, I was about to delete this question due to downvotes! Now I won't. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match entries like `90%`, but your regex requires a decimal point, and exactly two digits after it.

Change your regex like this to make the decimal portion optional:

```
@"^100(\.0{1,2})?|[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?%$"
```

Here is a demo:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^100(\.0{1,2})?|[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?%$");
foreach (var s in new[] {"100.00%","0%","100%","100.0%","90%", "90.1%", "9.00%", "0.1%"}) {
    Match match = regex.Match(s);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Success);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/n2WQlv)

Comment: I think you misplaced your parentheses, `(\.[0-9]){1,2}` matches `.9.9` but not `.99`. `100.0` may also be desirable to match.

Comment: @DasblinkLight- Still something goes wrong. Please review again. Thanks

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq Take a look at the change - this should fix the problem.

Comment: @Dasblinkenlight- Worked like a charm! Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (no need to put the regex definition inside the loop):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:100|[1-9][0-9]?|0)(?:\.[0-9]?[1-9])?%$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

for (int l = 0; l < resplitted.Length; l++) {
    Match match = regex.Match(resplitted[l]);

    if (match.Success) {
        bsc =double.Parse(match.Value);
        MessageBox.Show(bsc.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note: With this pattern, values greater than 100 are not allowed. If you want to allow trailing zeroes (100.00%) you can change the last group to `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})`